# Generating TFRecord format data from C+

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, tfrecord

I'm trying to use [TFRecord format](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord) to record data from C++ and then use it in python to feed TensorFlow model.

**TLDR; Simply serializing proto messages into a stream doesn't satisfy `.tfrecord` format requirements of Python `TFRecordDataset` class. Is there an equivalent of Python `TfRecordWriter` in C++ (either in TensorFlow or in Google Protobuf libraries) to generate proper `.tfrecord` data?**

Details:

The simplified C++ code looks like this:

```
tensorflow::Example sample;
sample.mutable_features()->mutable_feature()->operator[]("a").mutable_float_list()->add_value(1.0);

std::ofstream out;
out.open("cpp_example.tfrecord", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
sample.SerializeToOstream(&out);
```

In Python, to create a TensorFlow data I'm trying to use [TFRecordDataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/TFRecordDataset), but apparently it expects extra header/footer information in the .tfrecord file (rather than simple list of serialized proto messages):

```
import tensorflow as tf
tfrecord_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames="cpp_example.tfrecord")
next(tfrecord_dataset.as_numpy_iterator())
```

output:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.DataLossError: corrupted record at 0 [Op:IteratorGetNext]
```

Note that there is nothing wrong with the recorded binary file, as following code prints a valid output:

```
import tensorflow as tf
p = open("cpp_example.tfrecord", "rb")
example = tf.train.Example.FromString(p.read())
```

output:

```
features {
  feature {
    key: "a"
    value {
      float_list {
        value: 1.0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

By analyzing the binary output generated by my C++ example, and an output generated by using Python `TfRecordWriter`, I observed additional header and footer bytes in the content. Unfortunately, what do these extra bytes represent was an implementation detail (probably compression type and some extra info) and I couldn't track it deeper than some class in python libraries which just exposed the interface from `_pywrap_tfe.so`.

There was [this advice](https://www.reddit.com/r/tensorflow/comments/a7jd0e/does_anyone_know_how_to_create_a_tfrecord_file) saying that `.tfrecord` is just a normal google protobuf data. It might be I'm missing the knowledge where to find protobuf data writer (expect serializing proto messages into the output stream)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out `tensorflow::io::RecordWriter` class of TensorFlow C++ library does the job.

```
#include <tensorflow/core/lib/io/record_writer.h>

#include <tensorflow/core/platform/default/posix_file_system.h>
#include <tensorflow/core/example/example.pb.h>

// ...

// Create WritableFile and instantiate RecordWriter.
tensorflow::PosixFileSystem posixFileSystem;
std::unique_ptr<tensorflow::WritableFile> writableFile;

posixFileSystem.NewWritableFile("cpp_example.tfrecord", &writableFile);

tensorflow::io::RecordWriter recordWriter(mWritableFile.get(), tensorflow::io::RecordWriterOptions::CreateRecordWriterOptions(""));

// ...
tensorflow::Example sample;

// ...

// Serialize proto message into a buffer and record in tfrecord format.
std::string buffer;
sample.SerializeToString(&buffer);
recordWriter.WriteRecord(buffer);
```

It would be helpful if this class is referenced from somewhere in [TFRecord documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord).

Comment: khkarens: I'm having the same problem with differences between serialising example.proto and TFRecord. I've build tensorflow for C++ (via floopcz's tensorflow_cc) but now I'm having issues with compiling my own program due to the included headers in your answer requiring a whole host of .cc files). My program is built outside of tensorflow and only needs to serialise data via protobufs, and I'd really like to avoid compiling half of tensorflow's .cc files in my small program. How did you manage to compile the code above?